# Is it required to call streamSubscription.cancel() to free resources in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, if I obtained a `StreamSubscription` from a `Stream`, what is the proper etiquette to clean up resources when I am done?

1. `Stream` doesn't have a `cancel` method so I can't clean up that.
2. `StreamSubscription` has a `cancel` method but does calling `cancel` here also cancel the corresponding `Stream` too?
3. If the `Stream` closes by itself when it is done, will it automatically signal to `SteamSubscription` to cancel automatically, meaning I don't need to manually close it? Otherwise it will hold a list of listeners somewhere and prevent garbage collection.

I can imagine 2 hypothetical scenarios:

1. A `Stream` implementation that just returns a never ending list of increasing even numbers. Ideally, `Stream` should never cancel itself and shouldn't generate output unless there is an active subscription too. This meaning canceling a subscription should be enough to free all resources and prevent `Stream` from running further.
2. A `Stream` implementation that listens for clicks on a button. Ideally, the `Stream` should offer a cancel method when the user is no longer interested in listening to clicks. If the user calls `cancel` on the `StreamSubscription` only, will this also cancel the `Stream`? If somewhere upstream there is code that canceled the `Stream` such as the button being garbage collected, is the `StreamSubscription` automatically canceled and all references cleared?

Answer (score 4):

1. `Stream` has two types, "Single-subscription" streams and "broadcast" streams [[1]](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/Stream-class.html). single subscription uses `async*` which generates the stream within a method body, this is a cold stream that only works when it is subscribed to and it ends the stream when the method body is exited or when the single subscriber cancels. On the other hand, broadcast streams are hot streams that have a `StreamController` that can be used to emit to the `Stream` or cancel it but you would need to have access to the parts that generate that `Stream`.
2. Canceling the subscription will cancel cold streams since they have only one subscriber. Made an example for it [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9ff22b0c2551262ca56baf8012ce4466). And for broadcast/hot streams, you have full control with a `StreamController`, so you can cancel the stream or not, but it's recommended to do so when the last subscriber un-subscribes [[2]](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams).
3. When a `Stream` closes, it un-subscribes all listeners and then inform them of the event [[1]](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/Stream-class.html), you can pass a function to `onDone` when listening to a `Stream` to receive this event.

As for the titled question, the stream has a reference to your object when you subscribe to it and should be freed explicitly even though the `Stream` may eventually clean it up on its own.